# Where to set new UUID for PV & VG of LVM

Tags: linux, lvm, aws

I have 2 instances running on AWS. Instance A (main instance) and Instance B (rescue instance).

I detached volume from Instance A and attached it to Instance B to perform some changes why because I am unable to login inside Instance A due to SSH issue.

After doing changes on Instance B the UUID of the PV & VG are now changed. Now I cannot directly attach this volume back to Instance A as obviously it will fail because previous UUIDs are no longer present. How to tell Instance A to start using new UUIDs ?

Is there any configuration file in Instance A where I could update the UUID directly ?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to change the file `/etc/fstab`. In here you can specify where to mount which volume.
You can look up the current uuid by doing `lsblk -f`. That way you can address the LVs via uuid and tell you system where to mount them. After you configured your `/etc/fstab` do a `mount -a` to apply the configuration.

Important! `/etc/fstab` gets apply on boot, so make sure you dont have any errors when doing `mount -a` before rebooting. Otherwise your system probably will get stuck while rebooting, because it is looking for non existing drives.

Comment: But will the new VG get auto imported and activated during boot since this VG will have new UUID ? As I don't have terminal access to the Instance A since SSH was misconfigured.

Comment: If you have already attached the VG to instance B you should be able to see the uuid with `lsblk -f`. If that is not the case, someone else will have to help. That is the only way I know.

Comment: Yes on instance B i attached the VG and i can see the UUID.

Answer (score 0):

### LVM UUIDs

You seem to be applying the assumptions of the LVM of some other unix-like system to the modern (= kernel 2.6.0 or newer) Linux LVM.

When the system is booting up, the LV containing the root filesystem is not activated *by UUID*, but *by VG/LV name*.

In RHEL and related distributions (or basically any distribution which uses `dracut` to create its initramfs), you'll see a kernel boot option like `rd.lvm.lv=<VGname>/<LVname>` - that is all the initramfs LVM tools usually need to find and activate the right LV for mounting the root filesystem. (If the primary swap is on a LV, there is usually another similar boot option for it.)

In Debian and related distributions, a LVM-specific script within initramfs will parse any `root=/dev/mapper/<VGname>-<LVname>` or `root=/dev/<VGname>/<LVname>` boot option and will try and find a matching LV, *no matter which UUIDs it has*.

If the LVM tool of initramfs finds exactly one match, all is well and the LV containing the root filesystem will be activated. If it finds more than one valid candidate, then it will check if one of the VGs containing the matching LV is marked as *exported*, and if so, it will automatically prefer the non-exported one. If this does not help to resolve the conflict, the system will go into initramfs emergency mode.

After the real root filesystem has been successfully mounted, most distributions will execute `vgchange -ay` or equivalent, which will normally cause LVM to find and activate all LVs which have all their components present, and complain loudly about any PVs that seem to be missing.

None of this requires knowing the LV/VG/PV UUIDs ahead of time. The UUIDs are only used to check that the discovered set of LVs/VGs/PVs is consistent. For example, each PV that is in use will contain VG metadata that will identify the UUIDs of all the other PVs of the same VG.

If a VG is missing some of its PVs, then the LVs that are even partially on those PVs won't activate automatically - the administrator will need to use an explicit `vgchange -ay --activationmode partial` to also activate any LVs with parts missing if they want to recover data from the remaining parts of the LV.

So really, if you have only changed the PV/VG/LV UUIDs but kept the PV/VG/LV names the same, you most likely won't have to do anything at all for the LVM. If you have changed the names, check `/etc/fstab` and the kernel boot options.

### Filesystem UUIDs

As JadBlackstone already answered, if you have changed any *filesystem* UUIDs, then you'll need to edit `/etc/fstab` to change any `UUID=` lines to match the corresponding new UUIDs.

If your kernel boot options specify the root filesystem by UUID, then you will have to change those, too. (But if you are using LVM on your root filesystem, there is usually no reason to refer to the root filesystem by UUID, as LVM already provides you essentially the same protection against hardware configuration changes the use of UUIDs would provide in the non-LVM case.)

If you are using suspend-to-disk/hibernation, you should check how the hibernation disk is configured and adjust it if needed... but usually having this wrong won't stop the system from booting.

Comment: LVM is not on root. root has its own xfs filesystem. UUIDs were automatically changed by vgimportclone. Both the instances A & B are basically a clone. Hence UUIDs cannot be same. Let me try out now. And see if it works.

Comment: Fingers crossed.

Comment: Instance A is not booting probably because the UUID of PV & VG was changed. And now their is no way i can set the UUID to its original value.

Comment: anyways i got my issue resolved.I used the LVM volume of rescue system and attached it to Instance A.